# jest.mock('electron') behaves differently than jest.mock('anything-else')

Tags: jestjs, electron

**simply:**

```
import electron from 'electron';
import http from 'http';

jest.mock('electron');
jest.mock('http');

console.log({
  electron,
  http
});
```

**gives:**

```
console.log
    {
      electron: '/Users/.../node_modules/.pnpm/electron@25.2.0/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron',
      http: {
        _connectionListener: [Function: connectionListener] {
          _isMockFunction: true,
          getMockImplementation: [Function (anonymous)],
          mock: [Getter/Setter],
```

**question:**

why jest.mock('electron') produces a path to the Electron app instead of mocking it?
For other modules it behaves as expected